# session invalidate in JSF2.0

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'm using **JSF2.0 with jsp**.I'm trying to incorporate session invalidation in my project.I've tried using the following code.

```
<h:commandButton value="Logout" action="#{bean.logout}" </h:commandButton>
```

and my bean class contains the following method

```
   public class Bean{
    public String logout(){
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
      session.invalidate();
      return "login";
    }
   }
```

where string login redirects to login page.

my project has several pages which includes a header page..when i tried the above way...**it was working fine when i click on logout from the very first page...If i try the same after going to other pages, its not logging out**.Can anyone help me on this...is this the way we invalidate a session here???

UPDATE

I also tried using "*" in the navigation rule so that each page can be redirected to Login...but still the issue was same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return "login?faces-redirect=true"
```

as outcome so the browser does not use the same request for the login-page, which has the session still active.

Comment: Tried this too but couldnt solve my problem...can u suggest any other solution

Comment: It should work. Your problem is likely browser cache related. See also those lot of related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7739712, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7838910, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8062267, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7163051, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7437475, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this -

```
return "/login?faces-redirect=true";
```

If the view login is in the root directory.

Otherwise if it's in some other folder then as follows -

```
//if it's in the folder - folder1
return "/folder1/login?faces-redirect=true"
```

Notice `/` at the beginning of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `remoteCommand` tag and on logout call this `remoteCommand` using JavaScript and provide the implementation in `managedBean` for the logout and the implmentation is ok that you paste here just need `enter code here`to redirct to login page, or you can use again JavaScript to redirect to login page.

```
<h:commandButton value="Logout" onclick="closeSession();" </h:commandButton>

<p:remoteCommand name="closeSession"
action="#{jobController.logout}">

public class Bean{
    public String logout(){
          FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
          HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
          session.invalidate();
          return "login?faces-redirect=true";
   }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does that make difference? You are not explaining OP's concrete problem in any way.