# how to invalidate session in jsf 2.0 if browser get closed without being invalidating the current session.

Tags: session, jsf-2

if i close my browser without invalidating the session then i don't want it to access my application without being log-in again.

and don't want my user to get assess to the restricted user pages by using back button.

how can i do this in JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how to invalidate session in jsf 2.0 if browser get closed without being invalidating the current session.*

You can't do this programmatically in a reliable manner. The session will however automatically expire after 30 minutes. If you open a new browser, then a new session will be created and the previous session won't be accessible anymore.

---

> *and don't want my user to get assess to the restricted user pages by using back button.*

You need to instruct the browser to **not** cache those restricted user pages. You can do this by creating a [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which is mapped on an URL pattern which covers those pages and does the following job in `doFilter()` method:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if (!httpReq.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpReq.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        httpRes.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        httpRes.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        httpRes.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

This way the browser is forced to send a full HTTP request everytime instead of showing the page from the browser cache.

Comment: thanks for reply @BalusC. i already did it but i was looking something from JSF2.0.. by the way thanks for help.