# Difference between Session Expired and ViewExpiredException

Tags: jsf-2, session-timeout, viewexpiredexception

I've come across many solutions for the two 'huge' problems

- Session Expired
- ViewExpiredException

**My Question:** What is the difference between them?

I'm using WAS and I observed

- Restarting the EAR in the console does not cause the session to expire
- If there is a current ajax request and the EAR is restarted it throws ViewExpiredException but does not logout the user
- If the page is idle for, say 30 min, the login screen appears (I've used a sessiontimeoutfilter to handle this)

So isnt ViewExpiredException same as Session Expiry?
Also why doesnt restarting the EAR cause the session to expire?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)

Comment: i missed that question. thanks for the link BalusC!

Comment: restarting doesnt kill the session as it is persisted by your app server by way of serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to `client` will solve the problem.
Also using an ExceptionHandler and NoCacheFilter will solved the problem

I prefered the latter, since it is more maintainable.

**See**

- [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)
- [Check if session exists JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144195/check-if-session-exists-jsf)