# Handle ViewExpiredExceptions from AJAX requests with Primefaces 5.1

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, viewexpiredexception

I have a JSF 2.1 + Primefaces 5.1 web application and I want to handle `ViewExpiredException`s. Besides the configuration in web.xml (mapping the exception to a location via `<error-page>`), I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request) that we need to treat these exceptions when they are thrown during ajax requests.

Primefaces provides a `<p:ajaxExceptionHandler>` for this purpose. I tried to use it and, although I could see the exception being thrown in the server log, I could not do anything else. Maybe I'm using it the wrong way. How could I, for instance, send the user to the `index.xhtml` page when such an exception occurs, refreshing all ajax components?

I defined the exception handler factory in faces-config.xml:

```xml
<factory>
   <exception-handler-factory>
      org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
   </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

And declared the facelets handler in my template page:

```html
<p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException"/>
```

Here's my web.xml configuration for these exceptions:

```xml
<error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/index.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

After being unsuccessful with this approach, I tried the explicit definition of the exception handler ([Check if session exists JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144195/check-if-session-exists-jsf/8144420#8144420)) but without success either.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? (I'm trying to stick with plain JSF and Primefaces, although I know that Omnifaces provides a similar solution to Primefaces', but I haven't tried it yet).